How to accurately draw a Bode diagram of a control system in MATLAB in the case of its matrix being ill-conditioned?
I'm trying to draw a bodeplot of a discrete contorl system with the "ss" and "bodeplot" function:
% X(k+1) = AX(k)+Bu(k)
% y(k) = CX(k)+Du(k)
sys_d = ss(m_A, m_B, m_C, m_D, Ts);
h1 = bodeplot(sys_d);

It turned out that the result is not as expected in low-frequency domain (s close to 0, z close to 1), and I further check of value of transfer fucntion at z=1 by directly calculating C*(zI-A)^{-1}B=C(I-A)^{-1}*B:
transfunc = m_C*inv(eye(size(m_A))-m_A)*m_B;

And there is a warning "Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate."
So it seems that the matrix is ill-conditioned when z is close to 1, and the bodeplot function itself is not accurate. How can I solve this problem? Thanks very much!
I've also tryed methods like using function "evalfr" to calculate the gains at many frequency points, and the results are the same.
